# html "date" field is not working for ios only

Tags: php, html, css, ios, bootstrap-4

i have a simple html css form in which i have input type="date" field which not working only on "IOS"

```
          <fieldset class="form-group border p-3">
            <div class="row mx-auto">
              <legend class="col-form-label col-md-6 pt-0">
                Date of Birth
              </legend>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                   <!--<input class="col-md-3 form-control" name="birthdate" type="date"></input>-->
                <input class="form-control" type="date"  id="example-date-input" name="birthdate" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required>
              </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
          
       <style>

input[type="date"]
{
    display:block;
  
    /* Solution 1 */
    /* -webkit-appearance: textfield;*/
    /*-moz-appearance: textfield;*/
     -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    min-height: 1.2em; 
  
    /* Solution 2 */
     min-width: 96%; 
}

    </style>
```

i have also applied few solutions from search but nothing found useful ,
i am using cdn bootstrap, jQuery and other cdn links

thanks in advance

Comment: What's "not working" exactly?

Comment: Safari not support date picker for date type: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Comment: Safari on IOS does support the date type in input and if I run just your input line it is working OK for me on IOS 14. Could you put your code into a working snippet so we can see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution i found the safari or ios is not supporting the

```
 <input type="date" >
```

so i just replaced it with jquery
add cdn link for jquery and jquery-ui

html

js

```
    $( function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
  } );
```

so i just used the jquery-ui datepicker